# What is the origin of GraphQL's term "fieldAST"

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am working through all the GraphQL stuff I can find and have been using a variable called fieldAST which sets up a projection--in formal database terms--across the properties of the object being queried or mutated.

I cannot find where the term comes from, or what AST means as an acronym.  What is the deal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AST is "Abstract Syntax Tree". AST is what parsers often outputs as a result, it's a machine-readable structure that represents the actual code (GraphQL query in this case). Thus `fieldASTs` are parsed fields of the current selection, represented as their Abstract Syntax Trees.

Comment: how can I see fieldASTs on the code? I look at the schema.json file, and cannot see where it came from, how can I see it?

Comment: the fourth argument of the resolver is ASTs
and you can see it by loging it console.log(JSON.stringfy(ASTs, null, '\t'))